# what is list shuttle used for

Tags: java, richfaces

can anyone explain exact use of list shuttle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<rich:listShuttle>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_listShuttle.html) is a standard UI component that is used when you have a predefined list of objects and you want to user to choose only *some* of them.

For example, I have used it for selecting the days of week for which a given event is applicable. Initially all 7 are on the left, and the user can choose to move some on the right.

Additionally, the list shuttle allows for reordering the selected items.

Comment: thank bozho initially while reading through the theory i was confused

Comment: @meenus If you like an answer to one of your questions, you can 'accept' the answer by clicking the hollow check mark next to the answer

Answer (score -1):

> The `<rich:listShuttle>` component is
> used for moving chosen items from one
> list into another with their optional
> reordering there.

[Link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/richfaces/listShuttle.html)

Little googling will not gonna hurt you...